Interpretation of $\max \sup$
I am reading the regret analysis proof of LinUCB given in Lattimore's Bandit Algorithms. He makes the following assumption:
$$ \max\limits_{t\in[n]}\sup\limits_{a,b\in\mathcal{A}_t} \langle\theta^* , a-b\rangle \leq 1$$
What I understand from the above assumption is that the lowest greatest bound of the inner product of a fixed optimal parameter vector $\theta^*$ and two actions $a,b$ belonging to the decision space $\mathcal{A}_t$ for any time t is 1.
Now, he defines the instantaneous regret at any time $t$ as $r_t = \langle \theta^*, A_t^* - A_t\rangle$ where $A_t^*$ is the optimal action at time $t$, that is $A_t^* = \arg\max\limits_{a\in\mathcal{A}_t}\langle\theta^*,a\rangle$ and $A_t$ is the action chosen in that round based on maximizing the UCB.
He further says that due to the assumption made above, $r_t \leq 2$. I do not understand how the assumption results in this since both $A_t^*,A_t$ belong to $\mathcal{A}_t$, so the maximum lowest greatest bound is 1 at any time $t$.
Is there anything I am missing, or you can please correct my understanding of the same? Thank you so much.
Further, no sources on the internet mention this assumption whatsoever. They simply assume that the rewards are bounded between -1 and 1 and hence the instantaneous regret is upper bounded by 2. Are these equivalent assumptions?

Say what now? I am talking about the instantaneous regret at a time instance, which for a linear bandit will be the difference between the maximum possible reward and the reward got: maximum reward attainable = $\langle \theta^,A_t^\rangle$ and the reward got = $\langle \theta^*,A_t\rangle$.. I do not understand how you bought regression into the picture

My apologies - I suppose "regret" is a terminology specific to these "Bandit Algorithms". I often find questions where someone - usually a native speaker of some other language - will mistake a similar sounding english word for a common mathematical term. I falsely assumed that was the case here.

Since $1 < 2$, it is still true that $r_t \le 2$. And with the looser assumption about the bounds being between $-1$ and $1$, values between $1$ and $2$ become possible. It may be that he was repeating common knowledge about the broader case - still implied by his assumption - and didn't think about how his assumption is tighter. Or maybe there is a typo in the assumption, and it should have been a looser condition itself.

I understand, no problem.. In fact seeing it from your pov, you definitely should have raised the question in case someone did make a mistake unintentionally.. Thank you, the intention of this question was to ensure my interpretation is not incorrect in any way, I believe you have somewhat answered that!
